# Issue changing the text within a shape textbox using VBA based on selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox (not form control or activeX) and I want to change the text inside to "Modify Measurement" when certain cells are selected and "Add a Measurement" otherwise. I believe there may be something wrong with my syntax in VBA because I am getting a bug every time I try to run this. My code is provided below. I have flagged the lines with issues with the comment 'error.

(Note: we've had issues with ActiveX buttons, hence why I am using a plain textbox.)

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 3 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button_AddMeasurement").Visible = True
        If Len(Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value) > 1 And Len(Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value) > 1 And (Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 5) Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button_AddMeasurement").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Modify Measurement" 'error
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button_AddMeasurement").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Add a Measurement" 'error
        End If
End If

End Sub
```

Edit: I have already tried ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button_AddMeasurement").TextFrame.Characters.Text and that didn't work either.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057). The specified value is out of range.

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: Yes. Good catch. Let me see if that will fix it.

Comment: Spoiler alert: it will.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.